# How to make Microsoft Internet Explorer behave like a standards-compliant browser?

Tags: javascript

i am going to start a new project. In which i would like to start that project using this api http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ to ie7 behave like ie8. i did everything what the site is say. Now i am checking with ie7, i am not get any result. in case if i check with firefox it works fine ( firefox supports).

Any one tell me what i do wrong here ?

pls visit here to see my html with coding (pls open with ie7 to see issue) :

http://jsfiddle.net/g86pC/9/

In case apart from this solution, if any one knows even better one, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: You simply include a reference to http://magic.com/fixie.js. No seriously, half of web designers wouldn't have a job if you could do this.

Comment: but this link magic.com/fixie.js not work

Comment: @lourens was kidding you

Comment: use Google Chrome Frame?

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong library: you have used the one to 'Upgrade MSIE5.5-6 to be compatible with MSIE7' - you want to make IE7 behave like IE8 so you need the next one,

> Upgrade MSIE5.5-7 to be compatible
>   with MSIE8.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Edit: you also have the wrong color in your css:

```
p:first-line{ color : blue; }  // text says 'This should be brown'
```